# Cleaner way to filter collections in Java 7/Guava?

Tags: java, refactoring, guava, code-readability

I have the following classes:

```
class ServiceSnapshot {
    List<ExchangeSnapshot> exchangeSnapshots = ...
    ...
}

class ExchangeSnapshot{
    Map<String, String> properties = ...
    ...
}
```

SayI have a collection of ServiceSnapshots, like so:

```
Collection<ServiceSnapshot> serviceSnapshots = ...
```

I'd like to filter the collection so that the resulting collection of ServiceSnapshots only contains ServiceSnapshots that contain ExchangeSnapshots where a property on the ExchangeSnapshots matches a given String.

I have the following untested code, just wondering is there a cleaner/more readable way to do this, using Java 7, and maybe Google Guava if necessary?

Updtae: Note also that the code sample I've provided below isn't suitable for my purposes, since I'm using iterator.remove() to filter the collection. It turns out I cannot do this as it is modifying the underlying collection , meaning subsequent calls to my method below result in fewer and fewer snashots due to previous calls removing them from the collection - this is not what I want.

```
    public Collection<ServiceSnapshot> getServiceSnapshotsForComponent(final String serviceId, final String componentInstanceId) {
        final Collection<ServiceSnapshot> serviceSnapshots = getServiceSnapshots(serviceId);
        final Iterator<ServiceSnapshot> serviceSnapshotIterator = serviceSnapshots.iterator();
        while (serviceSnapshotIterator.hasNext()) {
            final ServiceSnapshot serviceSnapshot = (ServiceSnapshot) serviceSnapshotIterator.next();
            final Iterator<ExchangeSnapshot> exchangeSnapshotIterator = serviceSnapshot.getExchangeSnapshots().iterator();
            while (exchangeSnapshotIterator.hasNext()) {
                final ExchangeSnapshot exchangeSnapshot = (ExchangeSnapshot) exchangeSnapshotIterator.next();
                final String foundComponentInstanceId = exchangeSnapshot.getProperties().get("ComponentInstanceId");
                if (foundComponentInstanceId == null || !foundComponentInstanceId.equals(componentInstanceId)) {
                    exchangeSnapshotIterator.remove();
                }
            }
            if (serviceSnapshot.getExchangeSnapshots().isEmpty()) {
                serviceSnapshotIterator.remove();
            }
        }
        return serviceSnapshots;
    }
```

Comment: I'd check to see if Java 8 lambdas could simplify this.

Comment: Will not work anyway. Concurrent Modification. Use the Iterator explicitly to be able to call remove().

Comment: @duffymo, sorry java 7 only.

Comment: Too bad for you.  JDK 7 has already reached the end of its support life.

Comment: The code even as written doesn't seem to match the stated requirement. The code as written seems to be attempting to filter the ExchangeSnapshot objects, but the stated requirement is to filter the ServiceSnapshot objects.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz updated with iterator thanks

Comment: @PaulBlessing sample updated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using Guava:

```
Iterables.removeIf(serviceSnapshots, new Predicate<ServiceSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(ServiceSnapshot serviceSnapshot) {
        return !Iterables.any(serviceSnapshot.getExchangeSnapshots(), new Predicate<ExchangeSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public boolean apply(ExchangeSnapshot exchangeSnapshot) {
                String foundComponentInstanceId = exchangeSnapshot.getProperties().get("ComponentInstanceId");
                return foundComponentInstanceId != null && foundComponentInstanceId.equals(componentInstanceId);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I may have a `!` missing or inverted somewhere, but the basic strategy is to remove any `ServiceSnapshot` objects that do not have any `ExchangeSnapshot` whose ID matches.

Comment: Thanks Paul, though I also need to completely remove any ExchangeSnapshots from the returned ServiceSnapshots where the id doesn't match - see my sample where I do exchangeSnapshotIterator.remove(), does your sample cover this?

Comment: This example does not cover that, that's not how I interpreted the requirements, and the original code sample did not do that. This code can be updated to also do that in a similar fashion. I can update my answer shortly.

Comment: Looking at this again, I can't come up with a good way to remove from both lists without either looping twice or using the `Iterator` approach.